# Selenium, PhantomJS, Mocha combination fails on sendKeys command

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I have implemented the following technology stack for automated unit testing in the browser.

Mocha -> Selenium -> Phantomjs

I followed this example:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/headless-functional-testing-with-selenium-and-phantomjs/

I suspect that there might be a bug in the "send keys" command between Selenium and PhantomJs.  I do not have any experience in these 2 technologies, so I suspect it is rather me making some configuration mistake.

Basically what happens is that the characters sent by Selenium is not all applied by PhantomJs.

I switched PhantomJs out with Firefox and there it works like a charm.

The Selenium output for the 2 drivers are exactly the same.  So I am left with suspecting a bug in PhantomJs or Ghostdriver.  But as I said it might just be me not configuring the thing correctly.  Given that this is quite a big issue I really suspect that is the case.

I am also not 100% sure where to log this, if this is indeed a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues with sendKeys fixed recently.

https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs/issues?page=1&state=closed

Are you running the latest version?

If not I would log a bug there about it.